# adding constraints in PuLP optimization problems in python? pyschedule required?

Tags: python, optimization

I want to create an optimal meal plan with minimum sugar intake for 
7 days but the everyday diet plan should include food from 3 different categories. How do I add constraint that I could get food from 3 different food categories and give meal plan for 7 days?

my dataframe is as follows:

```
id      name               energy   sugar   Food_Groups
1       4-Grain Flakes      140     58.8    Breakfast
2       Beef Mince, Fried   1443    8.0     Meat
3       Pork                1000    3.0     Meat
4       cake                1200    150     Sweet
5       cheese              1100    140     Sweet
6       Juice               700     85      Drink
7       cabbage             60      13      vegetarian
8       cucumber            10      10      vegetarian
9       eggs                45      30      Breakfast

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("Simple Diet Problem",LpMinimize)
#create data variables and dictionary
food_items = list(df['name'])
calories = dict(zip(food_items,df['energy']))
sugars = dict(zip(food_items,df['sugar']))

food_vars =LpVariable.dicts("Food",food_items,lowBound=0,cat='Integer')

#Building the LP problem by adding the main objective function.
prob += lpSum([sugars[i]*food_vars[i] for i in food_items])

#adding calorie constraint
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) >= 
1800.0, "CalorieMinimum"
prob += lpSum([calories[f] * food_vars[f] for f in food_items]) <= 
2200.0, "CalorieMaximum"

prob.writeLP("SimpleDietProblem.lp")

prob.solve()

print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
```

EDIT:

I should not loop over prob.solve() 7 times to get 7 day meal plan.  Should I? Should I use LpAffineExpression to define a compound objective function ? or should I have an array of days and include it as constraint ? Please guide me

---

I tried the following code but it does not work

```
# Creates a list of the Food_groups
food_choices = list(df['Food_Groups'])

food_chosen = LpVariable.dicts("Chosen",food_choices,0,1,cat='Integer')


# Creates a list of the Days
Days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

days_menu = LpVariable.dicts("days_menu",Days,0,1,cat='Integer')

#updating my objective function
prob += lpSum([sugars[i]*food_vars[i]*days_menu[i]*food_chosen[i] for i in 
food_items])
```

Comment: research binary integer variables. There are some examples in the pulp documentation

Comment: How does the problem change from one day to the next?  In other words, is there some reason to think that the optimal diet for one day should be different from the optimal value for any other day?

Comment: @levis501I want to have "meat" and "Vegetarian" food_groups on alternate days. I have to add this constraint

Comment: @levis501 I have tested that looping days over prob.solve gives the same solution for different days, But I want to get "Vegetarian" and "Meat" on alternate days